# mysql script - mathematical solution

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I have a table with 16 columns:
Id, Product_Id, Sunday, SundayCnt, Monday, MondayCnt,...,SaturdayCnt

As you can see there are weekday columns and weekday counting columns

I would like to average the values of every week day ONLY if the value at weekday counting column is bigger than ZERO

Example

```
 Sunday=30    SundayCnt=0 
 Monday=27    MondayCnt=2 
 Tuesday=2    TuesdayCnt=0 
 Wednesday=75 WednesdayCnt=0 
 Thursday=2   ThursdayCnt=1 
 Friday=12    FridayCnt=0 
 Saturday=15  SaturdayCnt=22
```

for this example averge must take only (27+2+15)/3=14.66 because Cnt columns on those days are bigger than 0

Any idea on how to make this on a simple script

Comment: Is this an average for row? so for each product?

Comment: what type of average are you looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isnt going to be pretty.

```
  SELECT id, Product_Id, 
         IF( denominator = 0, null, numerator / denominator) as average
  FROM 
     (
      SELECT Id, Product_Id,
         (
             if( SundayCnt=0, 0, Sunday) +
             if( MondayCnt=0, 0, Monday) +
             if( TuesdayCnt=0, 0, Tuesday) +
             if( ThursdayCnt=0, 0, Wednesday) +
             if( FridayCnt=0, 0, Thursday) +
             if( SaturdayCnt=0, 0, Saturday) 
         ) as numerator ,
         (
             if( SundayCnt=0, 0, 1) +
             if( MondayCnt=0, 0, 1) +
             if( TuesdayCnt=0, 0, 1) +
             if( ThursdayCnt=0, 0, 1) +
             if( FridayCnt=0, 0, 1) +
             if( SaturdayCnt=0, 0, 1) 
         ) as denominator
      FROM YourTable
   ) as T
```

But you should consider change your table to

```
ID    ProductID   Sales   Counter   Day
1      1          30        0      Sunday
2      1          27        2      Monday
3      1          2         0      Tuesday
4      1          75        0      Wednesday
5      1          2         1      Thursday
6      1          12        0      Friday
7      1          15        22     Saturday
```

Then your query will be very easy

```
  SELECT product_id, IF(Count(*) = 0, null, SUM(Sales)/Count(*))
  From YourTable
  WHERE Counter <> 0
  GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Only problem is, that doesn't handle the divide by zero case. Adding an "if" to handle that will be even slightly less pretty, but necessary.

Comment: If all the counts are zero, this will throw a divide by zero error.

Comment: I think this is a good option, thank you.I wonder if there is a math function for example, for other purposes I have used pow(columnName,0) this results as 1 always.  But not sure if the mathematical formula exists for the weekdays situation I face now.

Comment: @DanBracuk Ok no need to panic, I fix the div by 0.

Comment: @GerardoAbdo there isnt a formula for that because is just special condition. If you put your column as row then you can use aggregated function. Dont know if that is an option for you? But you will get more flexibility with a row design.

Comment: @GerardoAbdo I include the row suggestion for you

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, just saw that columns are the actual day-of-week, and you want average per row, not average across rows.

In that case, yeah, you'll need formula that explicitly iterates over each column, adding weekday value to numerator and +1 to denominator when cnt > 0. I think the other anser given here should be sufficient, with one caveat: you should wrap denominator with NULLIF(...,0), to avoid division by 0 errors (in which case, when all cnts are 0, the overall average will evaluate to 0/NULL which will just be NULL)

<strike>In SQL, aggregate functions (like AVG, SUM, etc) ignore inputs of NULL.  So you just need to feed NULL to AVG whenever CNT is 0:</strike>

```
AVG(CASE WHEN weekday_cnt = 0 THEN NULL ELSE weekday_val END)
```

Comment: .... `As you can see there are weekday columns and weekday counting columns` AVG is for rows, no for columns

Comment: I just fix the div by 0

Comment: Got it - NULLIF() is a handy function, for future ref!